# Information about code used in spring

Tags: java, jstl

I am new to spring i have the following code can any one explain please

```
   <c:forEach items="${certificateToolState.certificateDefinition.awardCriteria}" var="criterion">
```

what is it means?

Thanks

Comment: var is an abreviarture of ${certificateToolState.certificateDefinition.awardCriteria}, maybe is a collection like List o similar..but c:forEach is JSTL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably an excerpt from a JSP file. It means that when the page is getting ready for render it will do a `for-each` cycle over the elements acquired from `certificateToolState.certificateDefinition.awardCriteria` and do something for each of them, while assigning them to a temporary variable `criterion`.

It's basically equivalent to this in Java:

```
for(AwardCriteria ac : certificateToolState.certificateDefinition.awardCriteria()){
    //...
}
// assuming that you get a List<AwardsCriteria>.. you get the point
```

Answer (score 2):

It will itereate the items in the collection `certificateToolsState.etc.` etctc and in each iteration the current variable will be `criterion`

Here's an example

http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/spring-web-flow-subflow-webapp-jsp-example.html

Answer (score 2):

It iterates over the collection specified through the object reference

It is basic Expression Language (EL), and JSTL (c:forEach) things. 
I would assume that the only spring element is that the certifcateToolState is a spring bean.

Basically what it means in pure code:

```
for (Criteria criterion :   certificateToolState.getCertificateDefinition().getAwardCriteria()) {
....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing is [JSTL](https://jstl.java.net/) code (some more information [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html)).

What it means is that there is an object in the model named `certificateToolState` which has a field named 
`certificateDefinition` which in turn contains another field named `awardCriteria` which is of type [`Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html).

This variable is accessed and each element in `awardCriteria` is placed in a temporary variable named `criterion'.

The Java equivalent would be something like so:

```
for(Object criterion : certificateToolState.getCertificateDefinition().getAwardCriteria())
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**This is a JSTL.**

The **c:forEach** command will iterate the **List** (**awardCriteria** is your list),

and hold each value of the list inside the **criterion** variable.